# Pass javascript array of int to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to pass my JS array of int to my asp.net mvc 5 controller and still gets 500 status after clicking submit button. I'm using jquery ajax request.
My request below.

```
$("#sbm-reservation").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ss = [1, 2];
    $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("AddReservation")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { selectedSeats: ss },
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = data;
        }
    });
});
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddReservation(int[] selectedSeats, AddReservationVM reservationVM)
    {
        AddReservationDTO addReservationDTO = new AddReservationDTO
        {
            ReservedSeatsList = selectedSeats.ToList(),
            UserEmail = reservationVM.UserEmail,
            ScreeningId = reservationVM.ScreeningId
        };
            reservationManageService.AddReservation(addReservationDTO);              
            return Json(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why ajax at all if the result is a redirect?

Comment: How I can pass this data in another way?

Comment: `<%
    Response.Redirect "http://www.sitename.com"
%>` in @Url.Action("AddReservation") and have that in the form action

Comment: Where AddReservationVM input parameter from? I can't see it in ajax

Comment: I use AddReservationVM to display data from DB in the view through GET action and need pass this array only to my controller. Array elements will be added after user click to some div. Element value is equal to div Id.

Comment: A moment ago i've changed POST to GET and it work. Why POST doesn't work?